# How to override PrimeFaces CSS to customize my button?

Tags: css, primefaces, overriding

I'm trying to simply customise a commandButton with PrimeFace but I cannot manage to do it...

I have read many answer over the net and I have put this in the body (to make it load AFTER primeFace's css)

```
<h:outputStylesheet name="css/layout2.css" />
```

When I check with chrome dev tool I can see that the button has this style:

```
.ui-button .ui-widget .ui-state-default .ui-corner-all .ui-button-text-icon-left
```

so in my css file I have added this

```
.ui-button .ui-widget .ui-state-default .ui-corner-all .ui-button-text-icon-left .mygreen {..}
```

and this my xhtml:

```
<ui:define name="content">
        <h:form id="formTable">
            <p:dataTable>
                ...
                ...
                ...
               <p:column styleClass="buttonColumn">
                    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-check" styleClass="mygreen" value="test2" id="mybuttontest" value="blabla"/>


     </p:dataTable>
     </h:form>
</ui:define>
```

But it still doesnt override the background color!

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will answer my own question. It appears that if I remove the space between the dots it's works...

.ui-button.ui-widget.ui-state-default.ui-corner-all.ui-button-text-icon-left.mygreen {..}

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to create a specific css for the button you want to modify. You can name it as #myButton and then can define the css components you need in the below block. You can also use the same name in the styleClass of the commandButton.

```
<p:commandButton value="Submit" id ="btnId" styleClass = "myButton"/>


#myButton .ui-button{
    background-color: green
    background-position: 0px 0px;   
}

#myButton .ui-button-text-only {
    padding: .5em .10em;
}
```

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

```
.ui-button, 
button.ui-button.ui-state-default, 
.ui-button.ui-state-default.mycolor {
  ...
}
```

I solved this way, where `mycolor` is my class in my css.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
.ui-button .ui-widget .ui-state-default .ui-corner-all .ui-button-text-icon-left .mygreen {
     background-color: green !important;
}
```

Comment: I will stay away from  ! Important.  This is a method for lazy people that don't bother understanding why things doesn't work